# What can invalidate SSL? (PHP-Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, ssl

I just starting working with SSL and one page in particular is giving me the error that my page is encrypted by 256 bit protection, but other areas of the homepage are not secure.

I use jquery ajax functions, but pointed the php request page to https://

I use include() functions and don't use full url (i.e. include thispage.php)

I use 3rd party javascript applets for analytics like clicktale, google analytics, and kissmetrics.

Can any of these be causing the insecure error?  What are other possibilities for causing this error?

Comment: have you already used ctrl+i on firefox to check that media are accessed by https?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- 3rd party Javascripts need to be included using https:// as well in order to avoid the warning. Google Analytics has  a provision for this; I don't know about the other two.
- Additionally, non-secure `<img>` elements and CSS references  like `background-image` are a common reason for this.

A nice trick to reference images with absolute paths is using a protocol-relative URL:

```
<img src="//domain.com/images/image1.jpg">
```

will reference the image either through http:// or https://, depending on what protocol the parent page is on.

Comment: Good point, I'm using the css & images from a subdomain which isn't ssl encrypted, could this be the main culprit?

Answer (score 1):

> I use 3rd party javascript applets for
>   analytics like clicktale, google
>   analytics, and kissmetrics.

That's what is causing the error. Some sites also provide these services over HTTPS though.
It mustn't be Google Analytics though, as it automatically detects secure connections.

Answer (score 1):

Any img, css or javascript file that has the full url starting with http:// can cause that error.